# Include Firebase into Firefox Extension

Tags: javascript, node.js, firefox, firebase

I'm having a hard time including Firebase (the BaaS service) into my Firefox add-on. My Code of the extension is as follows:

```
var Firebase = require("firebase");
var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://MYFIREBASEURL.firebaseio.com/");
```

This is at the beginning of my index.js.
I installed Firebase with node.js, using `npm install firebase --save`, according to it's documentation. I did this in the folder of my Firefox extension, and a node_modules folder came up, so I am assuming it is installed correct.

However the error I get when I test the application (it doesn't do anything yet) is:

> Message: ReferenceError: process is not defined

I appreciate any help with this.

Comment: I put the firebase.js directly into my root folder of the extension, now I get an error that Firebase is not a Constructor.

Comment: The problem is definitely the second line where I need Firebase as a Constructor. I checked the require with require.resolve and logged the file, it shows it is using the firebase.js in my root, so that should be fine?

Comment: Did you got this working? I'm in a similar position, trying to build a Firefox Add-on with Firebase support, and I'm getting `auth/network-request-failed`.

Comment: @Xisberto havent tried again yet. Chrome works so much better.

Comment: Yes, it does. Thanks for your answer, I'll ask for help on Firefox forums.

Comment: @Xisberto Report back please, if you find anything useful.

Comment: I've found on the `package.json` documentation, under the `permissions` key reference. I have enabled the `cross-domain-content` as follows:

`"permissions": {
    "cross-domain-content": ["https://www.gstatic.com/", "https://*.firebaseio.com/", "https://www.googleapis.com"]
}`