# Firebase is not a constructor - Firefox Extension - Implement SDK

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

I've downloaded the `firebase.js` and required it in my `index.js`, and it works, using `require.resolve` it points to the file.
However, the error it gives me for the second line is that

> Firebase is not a constructor.

The code I'm talking about:

```
var Firebase = require("firebase"); //Implementing Firebase SDK
var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://myurl.firebaseio.com/");
```

I studied other examples on Github (which are all for Chrome Extensions) and they do permission in their manifest.json, so I tried to do the same in my **package.json:**

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "2.4.2"
  },
  "permissions": {
    "cross-domain-content": ["https://myurl.firebaseio.com", "firebase.js"]
}
```

But nothing seems to do the trick. It seems like I can't use Firebase commands inside my script, even though the SDK seems to be implemented. Any advice?

Comment: Isn't this the same problem you asked about two hours ago? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37238426/include-firebase-into-firefox-extension

Comment: Almost, I'm sorry. SO was down for me (CloudFare thingy). Didn't know what happened with it. Still looking for help though.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as a duplicate. If you have more information on the problem, add it to your original question.